# Finding the pair of multipliers of x that most likely resemble a square like shape

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, ratio

I am trying to find the dividers of a number that are the pair that most likely represent a square

Take the number 36 for example, this can be calculated from

```
1*36, 2*18, 3*12, 4*9, 6*6.
```

And the number 72 can be calculated from

```
1*72, 2*36, 3*24, 4*18, 6*12, 8*9
```

For 36 the multipliers of 6*6 equate to a square

and for 72 the the multipliers of 8*9 equate to a the closest square like rectangle

I am looking for a way to calculate this rather than having to write out all multiples to work it out myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take the square root of the number that you are working with and take its integer component. Then find the closest integer to this value that divides the number you started with.

For example, if $x=36$, then $\sqrt{36}=6$, and we know $6$ is a divisor of $36$ and you are done.

For $x=72$, $\sqrt{72}\approx8.4$. So take $8$ which is the integer component of $8.4$. In this case $8$ divides 72 and your done.

For another example, consider $x=84$. Again the integer component of $\sqrt{84}$ is $9$. This time $7$ is the closest number to 9 that divides $84$, and $\frac{84}{7}=12$, so you get the pair $(7,12)$.

Comment: and in the case of 84 where the square root is 9.165 but 7 was the closest number that divides into 84, can you be certain that that number will be below that of integer of the square root as I am looking to write a computer program for this. Thanks

Comment: To be certain, I would look for the closest integer to the actual square-root value such that it divides the original number. The reason is that $x = (\sqrt{x})^2$ so actually $\sqrt x$ gives the side for a square, however the problem is that $\sqrt x$ is not necessarily an integer. You can get the closest integer by finding the closest integer to the square root that divides $x$. For programming, all you need is a list of the divisors of $x$ and square root of $x$, up to say 2 decimals, and you can find the closest divisor to $\sqrt x$

Comment: @jennyflysky One of the pair will be less than the square root, and the other greater. Of the two, the lesser will be closer to the square root.